# makefile: Reassign variable in each recipie to store the step name

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that runs a rule when it fails. I have written out a small example below:

```
temp = "start"

run:
    make run_all || make run_failed

run_all: step1
run_all: step2
run_all: step3
run_all: ;

step1:
    echo temp = "step1"

step2:
    echo temp = "step2"
    $(error fail test)

step3:
    echo temp = "step3"

run_failed:
    @echo "failed on step ${temp}"
```

I force this little example to fail in step 2 with the $(error ...) command.
The problem I have is that I want to set my variable temp at each step. But I don't know how to do that.

If it remove the "echo" before `temp =` in each step I just get a shell error (can't find temp).

How can I set my variable so that I can print out the step that the makefile failed on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: you shouldn't use `make` in your recipes. Use `$(MAKE)` instead. There are several very good reasons for this that you will find in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion).

Make variables and shell variables are different. When you write:

```
temp = "start"
```

it is make syntax and `temp` is a make variable. When you write:

```
step1:
    temp = "step1"
```

`temp` is a shell variable and you get a syntax error because shell variables assignment is `temp="step1"` (no spaces around `=`).

But this is not the whole story. Each line of a recipe is run by a separate shell (unless the special target [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) appears in the makefile) and different recipes can't be run by the same shell instance (regardless of `.ONESHELL`). So, you cannot expect the recipe of your `run_failed` rule to get access to the same shell variable `temp` as the one that has been assigned by one line of your `step2` recipe.

Anyway, when make fails on a recipe it tells you what went wrong, including what rule failed. If it is not enough the best option would be to equip each recipe with an error message:

```
$ cat fail
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exit 1

$ cat Makefile
run: step1 step2 step3

step1 step3:
    @echo "doing $@" || echo "$@ failed"

step2:
    @./fail || echo "$@ failed"

$ make step1
doing step1

$ make run
doing step1
step2 failed
doing step3
```

If, for any reason, this is not possible, you will have to:

1. pass failure information from one recipe (`step2`) to another (`run`),
2. pass failure information from one sub-make invocation (`run-all`) to another (`run_failed`).

All this will be extremely difficult, unless you use a log file and tell make not to run in parallel mode:

```
$ cat Makefile
.NOTPARALLEL:

FAILED  := failed.txt

run:
    @{ rm -f $(FAILED) && $(MAKE) run_all; } || $(MAKE) run_failed

run_all: step1 step2 step3

step1 step3:
    @echo "doing $@" || { echo "$@ failed" >> $(FAILED) && exit 1; }

step2:
    @./fail || { echo "$@ failed" >> $(FAILED) && exit 1; }

run_failed:
    @cat $(FAILED)

$ make --no-print-directory
doing step1
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'step2' failed
make[1]: *** [step2] Error 1
step2 failed
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, this makes sense +1. But it does not quite do what I want... I really want a persistent "state" really so that I can print the relevant final state to file at the end. I am guessing that this may not be possible? (i.e. can't set make variables in a recipe?

Comment: You can set make variables in recipes but as you do not master in which order recipes are run (not mentioning the fact that make can run them in parallel), it would be of little help. May I suggest that you edit your question and start with a clear explanation of what you really want? e.g. "I'd like make to be completely silent and just print at the end which recipes failed, if any"?

Comment: I believe I can force order with dependencies. I would still like to know how to reassign a variable in a recipe if (as you mentioned) you can do that? - I'll stick with my question title for the moment because I still really would like to know how to do that :)

Comment: Sorry to insist, but what you want to do is probably doable with much simpler ways. Mixing make statements and shell statement in recipes is really clumsy and error prone. Moreover, with your solution you will also have to guarantee that the make variable you set in your recipes gets passed to the sub-makes. Indeed, it will be set in `make run_all` and used in `make run_failed`. Anyway, you've been warned, if you insist, the make function that can be used in recipes to assign make variables is [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function).

Comment: Thanks, I really am paying attention to your warning... but I still really want to know how to do this. Then I might re-factor afterwards :). So I am trying to use eval. I changed the line in step1 to `$(eval temp = "step1")` then I echoed temp on the next line and it prints `step1` However in the last step (the error step) it still prints `failed on step start`... so it looks like the variable did not persist in the makefile :(    (or I am doing it wrong)

Comment: @code_fodder: "_so it looks like the variable did not persist in the makefile :( (or I am doing it wrong)_" it did, but you are now talking about two different make invocations. In the first one (`$(MAKE) run_all`) the make variable `step` has been assigned in the `step1` recipe. But in the second one (`$(MAKE) run_failed`) it hasn't, so it's value is still the one you give it explicitly with `temp = "start"`. As I mentioned in the last edit of my answer and also in my previous comment, you will also have to guarantee that the make variable you set in your recipes gets passed to the sub-makes.

Comment: @code_fodder: and this is extremely difficult, if not impossible, because the recipe of the `run` rule has already been expanded by make and passed to the shell. It is too late to change it. If you wanted to pass a make variable from the top make invocation to a sub-make invocation, I see how we could do this (`export`). But here, you want to pass a make variable from a sub-make invocation to another. Not sure it is feasible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177023/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-code-fodder).